# Does not implement inherited abstract member 'DbSet<T>.EntityType.get'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

After updating our solution from .Net 3.5 to .Net 6.0 -

[image: diff screenshot]

I am stuck with the following error in a unit test written by a colleague:

> Error CS0534  'TestDbSet' does not implement inherited abstract member 'DbSet.EntityType.get'

[image: Error screenshot]

Usually, I would just ctrl-click at the parent class to see the definition of the missing method, but when I do that, there is no `Get` method there:

[image: Decompiled class]

Could anyone please give few hints, what is missing in our code below and why has it changed after migration to .Net 6?

At [the EntityFramework doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore?view=efcore-6.0) I cannot find any migration notes...

```
class TestDbSet<T>: DbSet<T>, IQueryable, IEnumerable<T>
    where T : class
{
    ObservableCollection<T> _data;
    IQueryable _query;

    public TestDbSet()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        _query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public new T Add(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _query.ElementType; }
    }

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _query.Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return _query.Provider; }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Side question: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this implementation?

Comment: I am not sure, Igor. Maybe my colleague was creating a "mock database" for our unit tests? Where he saves some fake data into the `_data` collection?

Comment: It's the very first line in the `DbSet<T>` class

Comment: In that case it might be practical to change the unit testing strategy while you are doing the update to EFCore. The EF team shows how to unit test code that uses EFCore by using an in-memory EFCore instance. You then add your expected persisted values to that in your setup and use it in the test. That way you do not have to mock anything related to EFCore code.

Comment: Ah, thanks, Ivan. I have tried adding `override public IEntityType EntityType { get { return _data.GetType(); } }` but that does not compile (or maybe I need to add `public IEntityType EntityType { get { return T.GetType(); } }`). I must admit that I have yet to understand the code...

Comment: Well, seeing it was easy, Implementing it - not so as you don't have the necessary objects. Here is the EF Core [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs#L51), as you can see, they pass the `DbContext` and name to the constructor, which then is used for locating the entity type. Note that the return value is not regular `Type`, but EF Core specific metadata interface. In general it is part of an internal API, that's why you won't find anything about it in release notes/breaking changes.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you Ivan and Igor for the great comments (I understand how bad my question looks to you, but it is not possible for me to fix every problem in our larger solution while upgrading )

Comment: From framework 3.5 to .net 6? That's not a trivial migration! Are you also going from ef6 (or earlier) to ef core? Ef core had been rewritten, so also not trivial.